# OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication IsSuccessful returning false and I'm not sure why (custom client)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I have made a custom client for OAuth 2 (found here: https://github.com/ChrisB92/BattleNetOAuth/tree/dev/BattleNetOAuth) however I'm having an issue where `AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(...)` is returning the IsSuccessful flag as `false` however I know that the details I'm entering are correct.

I've tried to see if any exceptions are being raised by logging it with Elmah but nothing is erroring, so I am at a loss as to what the problem might be.

Snippit of the code that handles the callback, standard MVC Internet Application code:

```
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + (Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port) + returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }
```

Is anyone able to see any glaring issues with my custom client? I've tried adding it to an empty MVC application but it also fails at the same point. I'm guessing it might be something to do with the callback querystring?

AuthConfig.cs (for reference?):

```
        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new BattleNetOAuth2Client(clientId, clientSecret, BattleNetOAuth2Client.Region.EU, new [] { "wow.profile" }), "Battle.net", new Dictionary<string, object>());
```